# Should Gem assumes that other gem is loaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

We have a gem where we have a method `#display_name`, this method returns localized name if I18n gem is defined else falls back to default_display_name.

Following is the current implementation:

```rb
  def display_name
    if Module.const_defined?(:I18n)
      localized_display_name
    else
      default_display_name
    end
  end
```

We want to refactor it as on every method call we are calling `Module#const_defined?`.

Following is the proposed implementation.

```rb
if Module.const_defined?(:I18n)
  def display_name
    localized_display_name
  end
else
  def display_name
    default_display_name
  end
end
```

On surface level this looks ok but we have a concern that now we are assuming the require order of gem. So, my question is, should the gem assume the other gem is loaded (in this case I18n) or it should lazily checks like current implementation.

And any other suggestions for refactoring/optimizations are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [ruby documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require)

> `require(name) → true or false`
> Loads the given `name`, returning `true` if successful and `false` if the feature is already loaded.

it implies that if you `require` is not loading a file\gem more than once. for that reason, i will explicit state the requirement in the entry point of your program.

you can always test if a rubygem is present by using

```rb
Gem.loaded_specs.has_key? 'gem-name'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My question is along the line that should a gem assumes that it is loaded before its optional dependency. I feel like the gem should not make this assumption but want to know the thoughts of the community.

Comment: @the_spectator: this is exactly the reason that `require()` has such behavior :) assume nothing and be declarative when it is needed

Comment: Let me summarize, please correct me, the second snippet is not recommended in case of optional dependency as it can behave differently if the `i18n` gem is required latter.

Comment: Another clarification from my side, our gem will not load `i18n`. it is dependant on the end-user to load it to use this optional feature.

Comment: @the_spectator: if you use bundler in conjunction with [groups](https://bundler.io/v2.1/guides/groups.html), then the result is a set of rubygems available to your program, it should eliminate such surprises when it used correctly. more over, you can try and check whether a rubygem is loaded before taking an action (let me update my answer)